# How to render recursive components outside of parent component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion, vue-component

I have a tree data structure, and i need to recursively render it

```
const tree = [
  {
    name: 'hello',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'world',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'bye'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

the problem is that this component should be inside table as table-rows, so it cannot be nested in DOM inside each other

This is what it looks like
https://jsfiddle.net/zw4mydxb/2/

and this is the result i need

```html
<tr>hello</tr>
<tr>world</tr>
<tr>bye</tr>
```

is it even possible to achieve with recursive components and without changing data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for this, Following code snippet will help you.

```js
const tree = [
    {
      name: "hello",
      children: [
        {
          name: "world",
          children: [
            {
              name: "bye"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "hola"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "how",
      children: [
        {
          name: "is",
          children: [
            {
              name: "life"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
];

function getData(tree) {
    if (tree && typeof tree[0].children === "undefined") return tree[0].name;
    var outputString = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        if (typeof tree[i].children != "undefined") {
          outputString.push(tree[i].name, getData(tree[i].children));
        } else {
          outputString.push(tree[i].name);
        }
    }

    return outputString.toString().split(",");
}
console.log(getData(tree));
```

Now you have an array of name and you can iterate this array.